# Error while importing deepchem in a conda environment

Tags: pytorch, jax

I'm trying to import deepchem in a conda environment and this the error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/home/sumit/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3457, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)

  File "/tmp/ipykernel_749756/3064661951.py", line 1, in <module>
    import deepchem as dc

  File "/home/sumit/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/deepchem/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    import deepchem.hyper

  File "/home/sumit/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/deepchem/hyper/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from deepchem.hyper.base_classes import HyperparamOpt

  File "/home/sumit/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/deepchem/hyper/base_classes.py", line 6, in <module>
    from deepchem.models import Model

  File "/home/sumit/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/deepchem/models/__init__.py", line 74, in <module>
    from deepchem.models.jax_models import JaxModel

  File "/home/sumit/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/deepchem/models/jax_models/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from deepchem.models.jax_models.jax_model import JaxModel

  File "/home/sumit/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/deepchem/models/jax_models/jax_model.py", line 21, in <module>
    import optax

  File "/home/sumit/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/optax/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from optax import experimental

  File "/home/sumit/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/optax/experimental/__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
    from optax._src.experimental.complex_valued import split_real_and_imaginary

  File "/home/sumit/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/optax/_src/experimental/complex_valued.py", line 32, in <module>
    import chex

  File "/home/sumit/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/chex/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from chex._src.asserts import assert_axis_dimension

  File "<fstring>", line 1
    (rtol=)
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Please help.

I simply tried

```py
import deepchem as dc
```

and it throws me the error above.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using a Python 3.7 environment, but have installed a version of `chex` that requires Python 3.8 or newer. The problematic syntax is this style of f-string: `f"{rtol=}"`, which is valid in Python 3.8 but results in a SyntaxError in Python 3.7 (see [What's new in Python 3.8: self-documenting expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#f-strings-support-for-self-documenting-expressions-and-debugging)).

You should either update your Python environment to Python 3.8 or newer, or if you want to continue using Python 3.7, install chex version 0.1.4, which is the latest release still compatible with Python 3.7.